# pagebeforecreate not working in jquery mobile 1.3.0

Tags: jquery-mobile

The code below works smoothly when using jQueryMobile 1.2.1, but when using 1.3.0 it seems like the pagebeforecreate event is not fired.

Version with 1.2.1: http://www.karinedaelman.be/mobile.php  try entering 'hanne' after cliking 'Log in' button. The login button will be changed to 'Uitloggen' and the '...' button changes to 'Album'

Version with 1.3.0 http://www.karinedaelman.be/mobile3.php : doing the same as above will keep login button and '...' button unchanged.

How could I get this working with jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 ? Thanks for any suggestions

Here is the code:

```
$("#thuisPage").on('pagebeforecreate', function(){
document.getElementById('mijnalbum').href= "foto-mobile.php?token=0xmsxqkos0nvzpvily09bwihyy9o1or";
document.getElementById('mijnalbum').innerHTML = "Album";
document.getElementById('inloggen').href = "#";
document.getElementById('inloggen').innerHTML = "Uitloggen";
$("#inloggen").click(function(){
    DelCookie("paswoord");
    window.location.reload(true);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the DOM work you got going on after pagebeforecreate you might instead want to try pageinit.

```
$("#thuisPage").on('pageinit', function(){...});
```

If you dont mind me asking why you decided to go with regular javascript for dom manipulation instead of jquery built in selectors?

```
$('#mijnalbum').attr("href","foto-mobile.php?token=0xmsxqkos0nvzpvily09bwihyy9o1or");
$('#mijnalbum').html("Album");
$('#inloggen').attr("href","#");
$('#inloggen').html("Uitloggen");

document.getElementById('mijnalbum').href= "foto-mobile.php?token=0xmsxqkos0nvzpvily09bwihyy9o1or";
document.getElementById('mijnalbum').innerHTML = "Album";
document.getElementById('inloggen').href = "#";
document.getElementById('inloggen').innerHTML = "Uitloggen";
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried pageinit but that doesn't help... I also changed to jquery selectors as you suggested, it didn't help either.

I cannot understand why the code works with jQueryMobile 1.2.1 and not with 1.3.0.

Comment: I moved the script code to the end of my document, right before the </html>-tag. Now it works also in jQueryMobile 1.3.0 . I guess this 'solved' my problem, but I don't know why ...  ;-)